# Align TextView's text after setting the Left, Right, Top, Bottom values

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, textview

I'm programmatically setting the `Left`, `Right`, `Top`, `Bottom` properties of a `TextView` in the `OnLayout` method of it's sibling which it's supposed to sit on top of. However the text is **not** aligning in the center after I've set those properties. It seems to be aligning horizontally but not vertically.

I've tried setting the `Gravity` of the `TextView` as well as the `TextAlignment` but with no luck:

```
protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            _labelTextView = new TextView(Context)
            {
                Background = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(Context, 
                Resource.Drawable.blue_circle),
                Text = "N/A",
                Gravity = GravityFlags.Center,
                TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            };

            _labelTextView.Left = left;
            _labelTextView.Top = top + 20;
            _labelTextView.Bottom = bottom - 50;
            _labelTextView.Right = right;

            base.OnLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was needed was `_labelTextView.Measure(0, 0);` to be called after adjusting the bounds.

i.e.

```
_labelTextView.Left = left;
_labelTextView.Top = top + 20;
_labelTextView.Bottom = bottom - 50;
_labelTextView.Right = right;

_labelTextView.Measure(0, 0);
```